# Gradle sync error: Duplicate key AdditionalClassifierArtifactsImpl

Tags: android, gradle, threetenbp, threetenabp

I'm building an Android project. When I open my the project, during the gradle sync, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Duplicate key AdditionalClassifierArtifactsImpl(
    id=             ArtifactIdentifierImpl(groupId=org.threeten, artifactId=threetenbp, version=1.4.1), 
    sources=        /home/khongor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.threeten/threetenbp/1.4.1/412dfb27bd690a17f9de51863a65ccc3335572fb/threetenbp-1.4.1-sources.jar, 
    javadoc=        /home/khongor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.threeten/threetenbp/1.4.1/524c94e2a9d0d3f0ba8c4dba758ad2c292012e77/threetenbp-1.4.1-javadoc.jar, 
    mavenPom=       /home/khongor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.threeten/threetenbp/1.4.1/f0ed3678821f1d84940562243b0b78a13b5e5a3/threetenbp-1.4.1.pom, 
    sampleSources=  null
)
```

Relevant parts in the build gradle:

```
// ThreeTenABP
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.2'

// ThreetenBP - For testing
testImplementation('org.threeten:threetenbp:1.4.1') {
    // https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/issues/14
    exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp', module: 'threetenabp'
}
```

However if I do a manual *Sync Project with Gradle Files* the gradle sync is successful.
Someone has any idea as what could cause the error message?